# How to use custom_payload in dialogflow fulfillment using nodejs or python

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

i want to send `custom_payload` to my angular_chatbot but not getting response.
if any one can help me out. would be great help!!

```
` const payloadJson = {
            expectUserResponse: true,
      isSsml: false,
      richResponse: {
        items: [{ simpleResponse: { textToSpeech: 'hello' } }]
      }

  };
let payload = new Payload({});
payload.setPayload(payloadJson);
agent.add(payload);
}`
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The payload you created doesn't specify a platform and the payload is a payload for Actions on Google.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have created angularjs chat window and integrated with dialogflow api v2 and i want to send a custom payload to show my rich message to chatbot but i am not able to do that . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the response to your detect intent request there is a object called [queryResult](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#body.DetectIntentResponse.FIELDS.query_result).

In the `queryResult` object there is a field called [webhookPayload](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/QueryResult#FIELDS.webhook_payload).

The `webhookPayload` field will contain whatever was sent from the webhook which, in your example is `{expectUserResponse: true,isSsml: false,richResponse: {items: [{ simpleResponse: { textToSpeech: 'hello' } }]}`

Comment: Hi @matthewayne, i am not getting the **webhookPayload** in my response. if you give me an example how to use **webhookPayload** that will helpful . Thanks